# collision checking in XNA, if statement not working

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

So I am trying to use my current code to detect if my player sprite is coming into contact with a stationary object. I already went through the bounding boxes tutorial and the syntax they used did not work for me since I have my sprites variables set up differently.

This is the if statement I am using.

```
if (spritePosition.Equals(Booksposition))
{
   spritePosition.X = 0;
   spritePosition.Y = 0;
}
```

All I need is the syntax in C# for checking if the two are colliding.

This is how my textures are set up...

```
Texture2D myTexture;
Vector2 spritePosition = new Vector2(600,300);
Vector2 spriteSpeed = new Vector2(50.0f, 50.0f);
Texture2D Books;
Vector2 Booksposition = new Vector2(100, 300);
Vector2 BooksSpeed = new Vector2(50.0f, 50.0f);
```

When I run this code it does nothing, although it does compile and run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
if(spritePosition.Equals(Booksposition))
{
   spritePosition.X = 0;
   spritePosition.Y = 0;
}
```

You should try something like this

```
if(spritePosition.x >= Booksposition.x || spritePosition.y >= Booksposition.y)   
{
   spritePosition.X = 0;
   spritePosition.Y = 0;
}
```

The `>=` operator may not be ideal for you but I think you get the idea.

Comment: This worked, but only on one point. So I had to make a rectangle around the sprite and the object. Then replace sprite and book position with the corresponding rectangles. Simply placed the rectangles on top of the sprite and moved them at the same speeds.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is a late response but in the interest of providing info to others, how about a bounding box?

It's easy to do in 2D, just use:

BoundingBox myCollider = new BoundingBox((new Vector3(spritePosition.X, spritePosition.Y, 0), (new Vector3(spriteWidth, spriteHeight, 0));

Draw one of these around each object then test with:

if (collider1.intersects(collider2))
{
    go from there
}

You can use rectangles instead of bounding boxes but when  I was learning about collisions everyone told me to use the 3D tools and just squash them flat to 2D by setting the z axis value to zero.

I hope this helps (someone),
Andrew.